# Upgrading to 10.7.5 broke copy/paste system wide

Tags: macos, software-update, copy-paste

I upgraded to 10.7.5 through software update, and it appears doing so broke the paste command. I can cut (and perhaps copy) text out of fields, but when I try to paste, the Edit menu lights up, but nothing happens. This occurs either when I hit <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> or when I choose Edit menu -> Paste.